# How can i make an ajax call with one argument as map and on the java server side map it to hashmap

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring, jakarta-ee

I have spring java based web app.

In one of the places user will fill up a form and i have a piece of javascript code which will read each of the fields and makes an ajax call.

Spring now maps it to related function. I am good till this point.

Now I want to reduce the number of arguments in ajax call. So Is there any thing like map in javascript which java can map to ?

This is code without map which works fine.

```
       firstName = $('#firstName').val();
       lastName = $('#lastName ').val();
       address = $('#address ').val();      
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: location.href + 'MyApp/'+currentTabName+'/getResults',
        data: ({firstName:firstName, lastName:lastName, address:address}),
        success:function(data) {
            $('#searchResults').html(data);
        }
    });
```

controller side java code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Search/getResults", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getResults(@RequestParam("ticker") String ticker,
        @RequestParam("searchMap") Object searchMap,
        @RequestParam("dateRange") String dateRange,
        @RequestParam("inMarquee") boolean inMarquee, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
//code to process the arguments received
}
```

This works fine for me.

Now i want to put all three arguments into one map and then send to java code:

So i wrote below code:

```
        var map =[];
        map[ firstName] = $('#firstName').val();
      map[ lastName ]= $('#lastName ').val();
       map[address ]= $('#address ').val();     
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: location.href + 'MyApp/'+currentTabName+'/getResults',
        data: ({map:map}),
        success:function(data) {
            $('#searchResults').html(data);
        }
    });
```

controller side java code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Search/getResults", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getResults(@RequestParam("map") Map<String,String map,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
//code to process the arguments received
}
```

When i run my code: i get the below error:

```
 Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.Controller.getResults(java.util.Map,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Map parameter 'map' is not present
```

I feel this is pretty basic need for all java based web apps. But i reached this case for first time. So please share
you inputs on how to avoid this problem. 
Reason why i want to go for a map is the number of fields and the combination of fields can vary. so i cannot write ajax call for each combination.

Answer (score 2):

Please **COPY and PASTE** your code, **DO NOT** retype it.
If you copied and pasted the code than it is **NOT** working correctly.

```
   firstName = $('#firstName').val();
   lastName = $('#firstName').val();
   address = $('#firstName').val();
```

Pay attention where you get your `lastName` and `address` from

Comment: Thanks for pointing it. I didnt notice it. My only suggestion is this is not an answer. You should have left a comment.

Comment: You can only get an answer as good as your question is. If you post the code that does not do what it is meant to do (obviously) than it does **NOT** make sense (at least to me) to start fixing some other errors and problems in that code. You may have to replace the it anyway...

Comment: I understand the pain. My real intention in putting code is to make readers understand problem clearly.  You are right. if some one wants to try the code it will be pain.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a form, you can use `serialize()` function to build the POST data automatically.  So in `$.ajax` you can write something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: [a link],
  data: $('#formId').serialize(),
  success: function(data) {...}
});
```

Plus, for server end, in the corresponding method, you can use `@RequestBody` annotation and `FormHttpMessageConverter` to convert the parameters into a MultiValueMap.

Or, if you have a object corresponding to the form, you can use `@ModelAttribute` to map the form into a object.

Look here for more information: [Spring Web MVC Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)